# Difference between Salesforce and Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce

If I were to explain to a lay-person, who is somewhat familiar to Salesforce, the difference between Salesforce.com and Salesforce1, without delving much into the technical aspects, what would be the best way to do so ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about this isn't about programming, but something that a salesman would be required to know.

Comment: My problem to be precise. My explanations from a programmer point of view failed. However, I would be glad if someone could me some insights from a layman's perspective.

Comment: Explain it using user stories. Who is doing the task and how will the new version help them achieve their goals better?  You need to explain the benefits, based on scenarios that they can relate to.  Read "How to make friends and influence people" to get an idea how to express these concepts. It isn't their job to make your job easy, it is your job to show them how this new version will help their bottom line.

Comment: @JamesBlack Thanks! I'll look into that. Meanwhile if someone has faced similar situations, I would like to know how they dealt with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Salesforce.com and Salesforce1 can be accessed via a web client running on a PC, tablet, or phone.

Salesforce1 is optimized to work on a small touchscreen and can have functions via 3rd party apps to access iOS or Android features like GPS location data.

Answer (score 1):

[This?](https://www.google.com/search?q=sae&oq=sae&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2058j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20salesforce1)

Did you try googling you're question?

**[EDIT]**

[This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20935/what-is-salesforce1-and-why-when-would-i-use-it), and [this article](http://www.bluewolf.com/blog/what-salesforce1-platform-means-developers) sum it up better than I can.

The main points, boiled down are:

1) Developers can develop in any platform and it will work with SF1. Previously, it took sort-of a specialized knowledge to develop in SF

2) There's a command line that can be used to perform functions or get data and is specifically usefully and less time consuming for SF specialists and devs

3) "Committing to open source" means that the SF1 product will incorporate the best of the tech community into their product, for free

4) Integration with another cloud database company/system, Heroku, allows a broader range of data access - not just through the SF application

5) All of the SF product features will be available in mobile in SF1.

IDK - that's my shot at simplifying the explanations I've read. I could be misstating a technical detail slightly (which I guess is fine based on what you need) and I'm sure there are better ways of reducing the topic to more common language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well yes of course. To me the differences are very obvious. But somehow when I tried explaining the differences to an audience who were somewhat familiar to salesforce, all they could relate to was that SF1 was just a mobile app version of the salesforce.com desktop version. I tried explaining with the API first concept and that it really is a platform that integrates everything that SF has to offer, but all I got back was what's an API? Is it like some new language? Mind it, these people are senior resources who do have a wide CRM knowledge but fairly new to the Salesforce world.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had already read up the thread you provided in the first link. Thanks for the 2nd one. It's nicely written down there.